# Spring data fetch only without mapping to database

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-mapping

[image]

[image]

As shown in query and result, I want to fetch and add the result in list but how do I do it in Spring data. How to hold the result in a list?

Should I create a new entity class? Keeping in mind that I absolutely do not need to map my model class to database. I simple want to fetch and use the list in controller.

Thanks to anyone who can help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [projections](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections).

In your case, for example:

```
public interface TotalPerMonth {
    String getMonth();
    Long getTotal();
}
```

Then use it in your query method:

```
@Query(value="select date_format(...) as month, sum(...) as total from ...", nativeQuery = true)
List<TotalPerMonth> curentYearSales();
```

Pay attention on aliases in the query - they must correspond to projection method names (i.e. `total` -> `getTotal()`...).

Comment: Damnnnn, it worked! You sir are the Man. Thank you very much!