# Spring Data: Native Query, map to Custom Bean, Aliased Columns; not using a Projection)

Tags: sql, spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I haven't been able to find any specific solutions:

I have a Native Query in Spring Data, and need to map the resultset to a custom data bean object.

```
@Query(query = "select id as activityId, activity_title as activityTitle,
                 activity_instructions as activityInstructions   from activities_t  " +
               "where case when activity_code ~ '^\\d+$' " +  // Digits only 
               "           then cast(activity_code as int) between :firstId and :lastActivityId end", 
                  resultSetMapping="myQueryResultSet",         
                  name = "myQuery")
public List<Activity> findActivities(@Param("firstId") int firstId, @Param("lastId") int lastId);
```

The problem is, this needs to return a custom object, `Activity`, rather than the @Entity object `ActivitiesT`.

`Activity` is a custom POJO that has a subset of `ActivitiesT`'s fields, **and some of the columns are slightly differently named**:

**Activity.java, 3 fields** with getters/setters

```
activityId   (ACTIVITIES_T.ID)  <-- this is differently-named
activityTitle (ACTIVITIES_T.ACTIVITY_TITLE)  <-- same name
activityInstructions (ACTIVITIES_T.ACTIVITY_INSTRUCTIONS)  <-- same name
```

I found one solution here, but it doesn't work for me because I have a differently-named alias:
[Spring Data JPA map the native query result to Non-Entity POJO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29082749/spring-data-jpa-map-the-native-query-result-to-non-entity-pojo)

Their solution is to use

```
@SqlResultSetMapping(
    name="groupDetailsMapping",
    classes={
        @ConstructorResult(
            targetClass=GroupDetails.class,
            columns={
                @ColumnResult(name="GROUP_ID"),
                @ColumnResult(name="USER_ID")
            }
        )
    }
)
```

They assume in the answer that all the columns in the custom POJO are named the same as in the expected @Entity object. For me that's not the case. Also, I can't put a SqlResultSetMapping on my Spring Data JPA Repository method.

Any solutions to this?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50103729/5380322) can help...

Comment: @Cepr0 -- now I'm getting the error `Unknown alias` on some returned columns. They can sometimes be NULL.  `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown alias [activityinstructions]`

Comment: Futher info on this: https://jira.spring.io/si/jira.issueviews:issue-html/DATAJPA-1264/DATAJPA-1264.html

Comment: But anyway, what if I don't want to create a new Projection -- suppose I already have an existing data bean I'd like to use. I should be able to reuse it with a simple mapping.

Comment: What makes you think Spring Data sees that as a native query? https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/Query.html#nativeQuery--